# Transfinite Induction in Peano Arithmetic

Tags: induction, ordinals, axioms, peano-axioms

I have heard that Peano Arithmetic (PA) cannot perform transfinite induction up to [$\varepsilon_0$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_numbers_(mathematics)). This seems to imply that it *can* induct up to smaller ordinals, like $\omega$ or $\omega^\omega$ or $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$. How does that work? I thought PA couldn't even talk about ordinals, much less induct on them.

I suppose that PA can *probably* induct on $\{(a,b)\ |\ a,b\in\mathbb N\}$ with lexicographical ordering, which is equivalent to inducting up to $\omega^2$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: $\epsilon_0$ isn't very large, where I'm measuring "largeness" based in how much your head hurts when you think about it. (Church-Kleene is large.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track.  We can "talk about" a recursive transfinite ordinal $\alpha$ by defining a recursive relation $R$ on $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\{\mathbb{N},R\}$ is a well-ordered set with order type $\alpha$.  We can then define $\text{TI}(R)$ as the schema $\forall \alpha (\forall \beta (\beta \ R \ \alpha \implies \varphi(\beta)) \implies \varphi(\alpha))\implies \forall \alpha \ \varphi(\alpha) $, and let $\text{TI}(\alpha)$ mean $\text{TI}(R)$ for some recursive relation $R$ such that $\{\mathbb{N},R\}$ is a well-ordered set with order type $\alpha$.

For PA, we have that for any $\alpha < \varepsilon_0$ there is a recursive relation $R$ of order type $\alpha$ such that $\text{PA} \vdash \text{TI}(R)$, but for no recursive relation $R$ or order type $\varepsilon_0$ do we have $\text{PA} \vdash \text{TI}(R)$.

Note that the situation is quite different if we require $\text{PA} \vdash \text{TI}(R)$ for *all* recursive relations of order type $\alpha$; there exists a relation $R$ of order type $\omega$ such that PA does not prove $\text{TI}(R)$.  In fact, G. Kreisel constructed, for any true $\Pi^0_1$ sentence $\pi$, a primitive recursive relation $R$ of order type $\omega$ such that $\text{PRA}+\text{TI}(R,\Pi^0_0) \vdash \pi$. As I understand it, the idea is to "encode" the sentence $\pi$ into the construction $R$, but I do not know the details; for more information, I suggest reading Kreisel's paper "A Survey of Proof Theory". Of course, the previous result means there is a primitive recursive relation $R$ of order type $\omega$ such that $\text{PRA}+\text{TI}(R,\Pi^0_0) \vdash \text{Con(PA)}$, so by Godel's Second Incompleteness Theorem, PA cannot prove $\text{TI}(R,\Pi^0_0)$.

Comment: Does Gentzen's proof mean that, if we take PA with the addition of $\operatorname{TI}(\varepsilon_0)$, we can prove that PA is consistent? (I admit that I have not read the proof…) Also, if you can find details on that $R_{\omega+1}$ with order type $\omega+1$, I'd love for you to share.

Comment: Indeed.  Note that, in Gentzen's proof, $\text{TI}(\varepsilon_0)$ refers to $\text{TI}(R)$ for a particular recursive relation $R$ of order type $\varepsilon_0$.  Kriesel proved that there exists a recursive relation $R$ of order type $\omega$ such that $\text{PRA}+TI(R)$ proves Con(PA), and Beklemishev proved that for any recursive ordinal $\alpha$, there is a recursive relation $R$ of order type $\alpha$ such that $\text{PRA}+TI(R)$ does not prove Con(PA). But the thinking is that for "natural" relations $R$, $\varepsilon_0$ is the threshold.  I will edit the above answer wrto $R_\omega$.

Comment: Wait — a relation with order type $\omega$ is just a _sequence_, right? So, you're saying that there is a recursive sequence $(a_n)_0^\infty$ such that $(\phi(a_0)\land(\forall n,\phi(a_n) \implies\phi(a_{n+1}))\implies \forall n,\phi(a_n))$ cannot be proven in PA? Weird. I suspect that this has to do with PA's inability to talk about infinite series; I see why mathematicians prefer ZFC.

Comment: (I suppose I should mention that $a_{n+1}$ can be defined as the number $b$ such that $\forall n,(n>_Ra_n)\implies(n\ge_Rb)$. Or some such.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the purposes of avoiding confusion, you are using two different $\alpha$s here, right? Can we rename one?

Comment: I would say that there is just one $\alpha$, the recursive ordinal for which we are trying to define a recursive relation R with that order type.